# How to display a footer line above the footer using the pdfkit library in python?

Tags: html, python-2.7, wkhtmltopdf, python-pdfkit

## Background Info

I have the following Python code that I want to use to generate a pdf file. It uses the [pdfkit library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit).

```
import pdfkit               # import python module

if __name__=="__main__":
   
    
    options = {
        'page-size': 'Letter',
        'margin-top': '0.5in',
        'margin-right': '0.75in',
        'margin-bottom': '0.5in',
        'margin-left': '0.75in',
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
        'footer-left': "This is a footer",
        'footer-font-size':'7',
        'footer-right': '[page] of [topage]',
        
        'custom-header' : [
            ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
        ],
        'no-outline': None
    }

    ##this is the path of the whkhtmltopdf.exe in order for the library to 
    ##work on a Windows OS
    path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
            
    pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'Report.pdf',options=options,configuration=config))
```

The Resulting PDF is as follows. All I need simply is a line above this is a footer.
[image: The Resulting PDF]

According to to the following site, I can add a footer line above the footer using the attribute `footer-line` but I'm not understanding the syntax on how to implement it in python

> https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

## The Question in Brief

How do I modify the `options` attribute to include `footer-line`?

```
 options = {
        'page-size': 'Letter',
        'margin-top': '0.5in',
        'margin-right': '0.75in',
        'margin-bottom': '0.5in',
        'margin-left': '0.75in',
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
        'footer-left': "This is a footer",
        'footer-font-size':'7',
        'footer-right': '[page] of [topage]',
        
        'custom-header' : [
            ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
        ],
        'no-outline': None
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you just add the attribute and pass it an empty parameter

so to the `options` attribute you just add `'footer-line':''`
So it becomes the following

```
     options = {
        'page-size': 'Letter',
        'margin-top': '0.5in',
        'margin-right': '0.75in',
        'margin-bottom': '0.5in',
        'margin-left': '0.75in',
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
        'footer-left': "This is a footer",
        'footer-line':'',
        'footer-font-size':'7',
        'footer-right': '[page] of [topage]',

        'custom-header' : [
            ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
        ],
        'no-outline': None
    }
```

If there is a better way to do it please let me Know

Comment: Holy crap thank you!!  I was trying 'footer-line':'True' and 'footer-line': True, and they were not working. Thank you!